# Custom html for fee in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, fee

I would like you to ask, how can I add custom html for fee I am adding dynamically to the order?

**I am doing this way:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'apply_discount_for_subscribers', 20, 1 );

function apply_discount_for_subscribers( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $list_id = 3; // ID

        // Sprawdzenie subskrypcji
        $subscription_status = check_subscription_status( $list_id );
        if ( $subscription_status === 'subscribed' ) {

            $label = '5% discount:';
            $discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * 0.05; // 5% zniżki

            $cart->add_fee( $label, -$discount, true, 'standard' );
        }
    }
}
```

But what I receive is:

```
5% rabatu dla subskrybentów:
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <bdi>-12,50&nbsp;
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span>
    </bdi>
</span>
```

Basically it would be enough to just wrap this in div, but I cannot not achieve it:

```
<div>
    5% rabatu dla subskrybentów:
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <bdi>-12,50&nbsp;
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span>
        </bdi>
    </span>
</div>
```

BTW. why add_fee does not display as defined in review-order.php

```
<?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
    <tr class="fee">
        <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
        <td><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Please help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap div like `$label = '<div>5% discount:</div>';` but as you can see in `WC()->cart->get_fees()` loop label code use `esc_html` so it will not work.

So You can override the `review-order.php` template file in your theme. follow the below steps.

1. Create a new folder in your active theme directory called `woocommerce`.
2. Inside the `woocommerce` folder, create another folder called `checkout`.
3. Copy the `review-order.php` file from the `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout` directory to your newly created `woocommerce/checkout` folder within your theme.
4. Open the copied `review-order.php` file.

Change this code

```
<?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
    <tr class="fee">
        <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
        <td><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

to this and add a condition based on your fee label so it only applies to that particular fee `5% discount:` unless you don't want to apply for all fees.

```
<?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
    <tr class="fee">
        <th>
            <?php if ( $fee->name === '5% discount:' ) : ?>
                <div><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></div>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </th>
        <td><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I had the same structure of catalogs for the file review-order.php and overwrite template as you mentioned. I tried yours code to display discount, but it is not working like in my case. Basically I it has it's own html markup and ignoring one you and me paste... :|

Comment: I had reviewed your code and improved it a little, throws some errors -> it works! But... now I got duplicated information on my checkout page. Firstly it shows discount in new html markup, secondly old one...

Comment: Here is the new code:

<?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
         <tr class="fee">
             <th>
                 <?php if ( $fee->name === '5% rabatu za zarejestrowanie konta i zapis na newsletter' ) : ?>
                     <div><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></div>
                 <?php else : ?>
                     <?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?>
                 <?php endif; ?>
             </th>
             <td><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
         </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>